# Select values of list that not exist on a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of values in my PHP code. We could say:

```
$myList = array("one", "two", "three")
```

I'd like to select the values of the array that not exists in a table.

I've tried something similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (my-list-here)
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE value IN (my-list-here)
    )
```

I don't know how to select values from that array :(

Comment: So you want all values that are not in the `$myList` variable? Also, which PHP connection library are you using?

Comment: `"one", "two,` you realize it's missing a quote here and closure. Was that just a bad paste?

Comment: @fen1x why did you delete your answer? It looked ok to me.

Comment: Nope, i've misunderstood the question. My answer is to select all values in table that do not exist in array, not the other way around.

Comment: Well, I want to get the values of the array that NOT exists on the mysql table

Comment: @fen1x You should ping people back when you're pinged, that way it gets to them by being notified. I may not have been present in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if we can really execute a SQL query for an array and not a table like you've done

```
SELECT *
FROM (my-list-here)
WHERE...
```

What you can do is get the array of the values from the table using query and use `array_diff` to remove the values that exists in the `$myList` array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do this pragmatically:

**Your array:**

```
$myList = array("one", "two", "three");
```

**Get data from table (PDO library for example)**

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbName, $username, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the values of the first column for example */
$tableList = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

**Exclude $tableList from $myList**

```
$results = array_diff($myList, $tableList);
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I'd like (if possible) to do it in the query